# Nodejs Ajax twitter Oauth

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have an ajax call in my script for twitter authentication. Its not working and giving me an error. How do I redirect the user to a twitter login and then back using ajax?
My AJAX code:

```
var login = $.ajax({
                                          url: "http://paybyshare.herokuapp.com/twitterlogin",
                                          method: "GET",
                                          data: { shop_name: shopname },
                                          dataType: "json"
                                        });

                                        login.done(function(msg) {
                                            alert("reached")
                                        });

                                        login.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                                          alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                                        });
```

My Nodejs code:

```
app.get('/twitterlogin',function(req,res){
  twitter.getRequestToken(function(error, requestToken, requestTokenSecret, results){
    if (error) {
     console.log('Error:', error);
    } else {
      //store token and tokenSecret somewhere, you'll need them later; redirect user 
      req.session.requestToken=requestToken;
      req.session.requestTokenSecret=requestTokenSecret;

       var twitter_auth_url = twitter.getAuthUrl(requestToken);

       res.redirect(twitter_auth_url);
    }
  });
});

app.get('/twitter',function(req,res){

  twitter.getAccessToken(req.query.oauth_token, req.session.requestTokenSecret, req.query.oauth_verifier, function(error, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, results) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      req.session.twitter_access_token=accessToken;
      req.session.twitter_access_token_secret=accessTokenSecret;

      twitter.verifyCredentials(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, function(error, data, response) {
          if (error) {
            res.redirect('/twitterlogin');
          } else {
            console.log(data["screen_name"]);
            res.json(data)
          }
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I dont know. it just shows error. i dont see a popup window for login also. I think thats the issue